# The 'Open with' option is automatically changed with my app when my app is installed

Tags: macos, open-with

I am developing an Desktop application which organizes and plays movie files. So, I have added the mp4, mov, avi, m4v (mp4, mov, avi, m4v extensions) as document type under Properties of my application target.
The problem is that when the user installs my app in Applications folder of his system, the default option for opening the mp4 movie file changes to Voila from QuickTime Player automatically. The default option is nothing but the 'Open With' option provided in the Info window of a file. This happens for most of the users. Why is this happening? How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you somehow define your app in LaunchServices as a default handler? [Apple´s Documentation on LaunchServices][1] specifies LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType - did you use that? 

  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: No Asmus. I have not used LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType in my application. I have used only document types under Properties of my application target as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer could be found here:  http://markmail.org/message/kf7lxgpu52nn34k2